# Where does Rabbeinu Tam discuss the "aspaklaria ha-meira"?

Tags: sources-mekorot, agada-stories-legends, masechet-yevamot, rabbeinu-tam

In Bernard-Henri Levy's book, "The Genius of Judaism", on p222-3, the author describes what appears to be the discussion in the gemara in Yevamot 49b about Moshe's level of prophecy. He says that Rabbeinu Tam raises a fundamental question about the meaning of the phrase "aspaklaria ha-meira". The relevant section of Levy's book is pasted below, from Google Books. I am searching for the original source of Rabbeinu Tam's comment -- where does Rabbeinu Tam say this?

[image: "The Genius of Judaism", on p222-3,]

Comment: @kouty not him and not in there

Comment: One hit on Sefaria for this phase in Da’as Zekeinim, which has nothing to do with the topic at hand, and no hits for anywhere in Tosfos on Shas.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the previous paragraph includes an embellishment. R"T very likely knew Henri of Champagne (per a letter he sent him) and he also had a hawk with silver talons (Tosfot Rosh on Chullin) but I don't know of evidence that he actually went riding with him. So perhaps the next idea is also embellished somehow.